Vlookup is failing to take different formats of ID in Excel from LO99 to LO100?

I am working on automating the calculation of remaining amount by linking different pages with the 'Loan ID' by using this formula
=VLOOKUP(A3256, 'Master Data Sheet'!$A$2:$E$100, 5, FALSE) - SUMIFS(C$2:C3256, A$2:A3256, A3256)

but its working for Loan Id LO99.  when it comes to LO100, its not. what might be the reason?
I am expecting a formula which will take both the formats of Loan ID.

Is your data for vlookup ordered the way it needs to be? Vlookup does not use any formats, just text, but you might be ordering it in a numeric order and not in character case order.

Any leading or trailing spaces?

Maybe your lookup range needs to be 'lengthened', i.e. if there's a header row on Master Data Sheet then LO99 is probably the last lookup value, on row 100. Also, while the SUMIFS() function you've included in your Question looks ok, the one in your screenshot doesn't i.e. C$2:C3256 vs D$2:D3255

To troubleshoot some of the cases suggested, you could enter in an empty cell =VLOOKUP(TRIM(A3256), TRIM('Master Data Sheet'!$A$2:$E$100), 5, FALSE) and if it fails, then  =VLOOKUP(TRIM(A3256), TRIM('Master Data Sheet'!$A$2:$E$100), 5, TRUE) to get some idea.
